# Working out the curvature of a curve

Tags: integration, geometry

I am told to work out the curvature of a curve $y(t) = (t, \cosh t)$.

The formula we use for calculating curvature, $K$, is given by:
$K = T'(t)/\|y'(t)\|$.

Where $T$ is $y'(t)/\|y'(t)\|$.

I get $T(t)$ to be $(1,\sinh t)/\cosh t$.

I am unsure how to differentiate this and would appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you mean by $y(x)=(1, \cosh t)$?

Answer (score 1):

If $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ here is the famous formula to compute [curvature of a curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Local_expressions):
$$\kappa=\frac{x'y''-y'x''}{(x'^2+y'^2)^{3/2}}$$
equivalently $$\kappa=\frac{\det(\gamma',\gamma'')}{||\gamma'||^3}$$
Now if $\gamma (t)=(t,\cosh t)$ then $\gamma' (t)=(1,\sinh t)$ and $\gamma''(t)=(0,\cosh t)$ and so

$$\det(\gamma',\gamma'')=\cosh t$$ and $$||\gamma'(t)||=\sqrt{1+\sinh^2 t}=\cosh t$$ And so curvature of this curve is
$$\kappa=\frac{\cosh t}{\cosh^3 t}=\frac{1}{\cosh^2 t}$$